# Disable a column for being handled in a EditEnd event datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is there a way to disable the handling when a cell was edit for a specific column?

I don't want to make a condition for the column in the event , I want it to not being handled at all.

something like this Algo :

```
mydatagridview.Columns(4).beingHandledByTheEvent(eventName) = false
```

Or Maybe make a custom event that's occur when the user finish editing a specific cell in a specific column only.

Comment: If you are looking for a property on column that disable raising the `CellEndEdit` event, there is no such property.

Comment: My question is why do you not want to put a condition in the event handler? Do you have a reason other than "just because"?

Comment: My code was based on editing one cell in a DataGidView  the rest of cels are read only , I want to get the current cell changed after edit have end. If the user edit the cell and click to another cell after finish the edit the current cell will be the readOnly cell , It will cause a problem form me.